# I am not able to use viewpager inside scroll-view and tab layout without toolbar layout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to use

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/action_bar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    tools:visibility="gone">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="220dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/cover_image"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/image"
                        android:background="@color/card_background">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/topTabs"
                            style="@style/TextAppearance.Tab"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:tabBackground="@color/bpWhite"
                            app:tabGravity="fill"
                            app:tabMode="fixed"
                            app:tabTextColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                            custom:tabIndicatorColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                            custom:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/topTabs"
                            android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_drop_shadow" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It is not able to scroll, that view-pager or tab-layout is not able scroll I tried all the ways.

1.Disable the touch event in view-pager and enable the touch event for scroll-view.

2.Tried other scroll-views like Nestedscrollview, Parallaxscrollview, Coordinator layout.If I use coordinator layout then not able to change he toolbar.

3. I used fillviewport true for all the scrollviews. but still it is not able to scroll.

**Any Other ways to fix the issue.**

Comment: Can you add your full xml where you have tried

Comment: I can't read your XML. What's all that clutter at the top?

Comment: @KalaBalik can u check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use view pager without the toolbar, but you can't use the tabs without the toolbar.

Comment: can you tell me how to use coordinator layout without toolbar

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: If you are using the latest android studio, the coordinator layout is usually added when a new project is created.

Answer (score 0):

Although it remains unclear, what you are trying to achieve here, there is no problem in the layout, really.

If you set up the Design Support Library [correctly](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Design-Support-Library) and

if you did not mess up your listeners with your attempts to disable some touch events and

if you take out the `tools:visibility="gone"` attribute (in order to show anything that can be scrolled) and

if you decide on a specific height (or `wrap_content`) for the `ViewPager` and

optionally if you take out the first `RelativeLayout`s which is unnecessary,

then you should be able to scroll. At least I am inside the layout editor of Android Studio.

Comment: I don't want to give fixed height to he viewpager, in side viewpager I have 2 fragment one with recyclerview and one with normal Liner layout, I didn't used any touch events also.Still it is not able to scroll

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem.